# Cytoscape JS CoSe Layout Label Length Effect

Tags: cytoscape.js

I made an observation with Cytoscape Layout and I am wondering how to change it. The layout manager CoSe produces different results depending on the length of the label name. I encountered this when I changed the node label from a long to a short id and also to no id. The best result is produced with no id.

How to deactivate this label layout effect ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a planned feature to specify how the bounding box is calculated for nodes in a layout: https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/issues/1626

Before that's implemented, you'll have to hide labels while the layout is running.

E.g.

```
cy.nodes().addClass('no-labels');
cy.one('layoutstop', () => cy.nodes().removeClass('no-labels'));
cy.makeLayout({ ... }).run();
```

Where `node.no-labels { label: '' }` is defined in your stylesheet.